# iOS app update notification / alert

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I'm getting this by the Apple App Review Board:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your reply. It is not appropriate for applications to direct users to the App Store through the use of a notification or alert message. On the initial launch of your application, users were presented with an alert message that gives them the option to update the app or be reminded at a later time.
>
> To be reconsidered for the App Store, please remove the update feature from your app. To distribute a new version of your app, upload the new app binary version into the same iTunes Connect record you created for the app’s previous version. Updated versions keep the same Apple ID, iTunes Connect ID (SKU), and bundle ID as the original version, and are available free to customers who purchased a previous version.
>
> Resources
>
> To create new versions of your app, please see Replacing Your App with a New Version in the iTunes Connect Developer Guide.
>
> Best Regards,
>   App Store Review Team

Previously, this was fine (few months back). And suddenly, when I tried to update my app, this is what they said. But I've been seeing a lot of apps already doing this. So I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: I'm wondering if anyone out there have experienced the same

Comment: Where you using [Harpy](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy) by chance?

Comment: Nope.. I was using my own method.. Not harpy

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Harpy](http://github.com/artsabintsev/harpy) or [Siren](http://github.com/artsabintsev/swift), as it doesn't show the App Reviewer the alert. It only presents the alert once the app is in production.

Disclaimer, I wrote both those libraries, and @MikeStrand notified me of this post.

Comment: [This is the correct link for Siren](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren).